# how to extract all image urls from a html source and download them using curl?

Tags: php, html, curl

I am using curl to get the images from html source code of an external webpage. I am     getting **`img original='imageurl'`** on *view page source* in Firefox. But when i select the particular images then it shows **`img src='imageurl'`** on *view selection source* in in Firefox.

How can I get this type of image using curl?

Currently I am using regex to get the image:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$output, $result);   
print_r($result);
```

But it doesn't display any image.

I am very confused about what to do here. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: What is *"view selection source"*? Are you using a specific browser? If so, what does it return if you disable javascript in your browser? curl won't do javascript as well, so this would be the first place I would check. Additionally install the [curl commandline tool](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) to your computer as well, so you can better debug things.

Comment: I am using firefox for view page source and it shows img original='imageurl'. it does not show img src= 'imageurl'. how can i get the image. it shows same thing in chrome and IE also.

Comment: Your SECOND post on this topic is STILL porely written, you need to consider what your question sounds like to someone else. It looks like you have 2 problems but we can't be sure... is cURL giving you the response you expected? are you having a problem extracting the image source???

Answer (score 3):

> I am very confused about what to do here.

The confusion probably results from that you use your webbrowser to view the source of an URL. Even if it's often the case that the source of the page displayed by the webbrowser is the data that curl would return as well, this is not always the case.

Especially the Firefox feature *view selection source* will not display that selection from the original resource, but often something else. To prevent that, you need to [disable javascript in your Firefox browser<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/JavaScript). Because often documents are modified with javascript and you want to see the original, not the modification because curl is not able to run javascript, it can only get "the original".

> Anyone have any thoughts?

1. Disable javascript in your browser.
2. Reload the page.
3. Locate the fragment of the HTML-source-code you're interested in.
4. Write it down, e.g. into a string.
5. Request the page with CURL. Output the source.
6. Locate that string in there. If it's not in there, search the curl request result for the string you're interested and use that instead.
7. Write a regular expression that is able to obtain what you need from that string.
8. Use that regular expression in your program then.

Comment: Or just refer to cURL's exact result!!

Comment: See step 5, that's part of the procedure. The important part here is to see if it differs. Also please see my comment above to use the [curl command-line tool](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your web browser is reformatting the HTML according to how it understands/parses the HTML page.

When you choose *"View Page Source"* it shows you the original source code served from the server.

When you select content and choose *"View Selection Source"* it shows what the browser has parsed into DOM (what the browser understands) for the selected content.

I am guessing you're using Firefox

If you are attempting to use cURL to process the HTML served from the server, you must not look at *"View Selection Source"* of the page, always refer to *"View Page Source"*..

**Ultimately**

You should rather refer to the ACTUAL result from cURL

For example:

```
$content = curl_exec($ch);

header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo $content;
```

That should echo exactly what cURL has received from the server...

**NOTE**: This is a re-post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754844/can-not-get-images-using-curl

---

**Furthermore**

If you want to fetch the actual image inside a `<img src="">` tag then you need to pin-point the IMG tag in the result HTML response using preg_match, and do a seperate cURL request to the IMG SRC

Comment: Note: Header("Content-type: text/plain"); is to display the content as plain text, as if you're viewing the source in a text editor

Comment: http://www.target.com/c/baby-baby-bath-bath-safety/-/N-5xtji#?lnk=nav_t_spc_3_inc_1_1  This is the site url about which i am talkig. Please first check the page source of this site url. and let me know what i have to do, Plz.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are TRYING to do.... PLEASE explain it better, rather edit your question and elaborate on it for future readers